# how to use AMDeviceInstallApplication

Tags: ios, installation, ipa

I found this site,  https://github.com/ghughes/fruitstrap/blob/master/fruitstrap.c

first of all, he use `AMDeviceTransferApplication` to transfer file to ios device,

```
path = /PublicStaging/*.ipa
```

second, he use `AMDeviceInstallApplication` to install ipa file.

```
AMDeviceInstallApplication(installFd, path, options, install_callback, NULL);
```

my question is how to create options in C#.

my code is:

```
int value2 = MobileDevice.AMDeviceInstallApplication(installFd, MobileDevice.CFStringMakeConstantString("c:/Google_Translate_v1.3.1.2978(os3.0).ipa"), null, null, null);
```

value2's output is -402653104.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the app bundle (`.app` folder, say from Xcode's build folder) not the `.ipa` file.